# How to increase Dataflow read parallelism from Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to export a lot of data (2 TB, 30kkk rows) from Cassandra to BigQuery. All my infrastructure is on GCP.  My Cassandra cluster have 4 nodes (4 vCPUs, 26 GB memory, 2000 GB PD (HDD) each). There is one seed node in the cluster. I need to transform my data before writing to BQ, so I am using Dataflow. Worker type is `n1-highmem-2`. Workers and Cassandra instances are at the same zone `europe-west1-c`. My limits for Cassandra:

[image: Cassandra limits settings]

Part of my pipeline code responsible for reading transform is located [here](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1691645).

## Autoscaling

The problem is that when I don't set `--numWorkers`, the autoscaling set number of workers in such manner (2 workers average):

[image: Worker number with autoscaling]

## Load balancing

When I set `--numWorkers=15` the rate of reading doesn't increase and only 2 workers communicate with Cassandra (I can tell it from `iftop` and only these workers have CPU load ~60%).

At the same time Cassandra nodes don't have a lot of load (CPU usage 20-30%). Network and disk usage of the seed node is about 2 times higher than others, but not too high, I think:

[image: Network usage of the seed]

[image: Disk usage of the seed node]

And for the not seed node here:

[image: Network usage of the not seed]

[image: Disk usage of the not seed node]

## Pipeline launch warnings

I have some warnings when pipeline is launching:

```
WARNING: Size estimation of the source failed: 
org.apache.beam.sdk.io.cassandra.CassandraIO$CassandraSource@7569ea63
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /10.132.9.101:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/10.132.9.101:9042] Cannot connect), /10.132.9.102:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/10.132.9.102:9042] Cannot connect), /10.132.9.103:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/10.132.9.103:9042] Cannot connect), /10.132.9.104:9042 [only showing errors of first 3 hosts, use getErrors() for more details])
```

My Cassandra cluster is in GCE local network and it seams that some queries are made from my local machine and cannot reach the cluster (I am launching pipeline with Dataflow Eclipse plugin as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-eclipse)). These queries are about size estimation of tables. Can I specify size estimation by hand or launch pipline from GCE instance? Or can I ignore these warnings? Does it have effect on rate of read?

I'v tried to launch pipeline from GCE VM. There is no more problem with connectivity. I don't have varchar columns in my tables but I get such warnings (no codec in datastax driver [varchar <-> java.lang.Long]). :

```
WARNING: Can't estimate the size
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [varchar <-> java.lang.Long]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.notFound(CodecRegistry.java:741)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.createCodec(CodecRegistry.java:588)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.access$500(CodecRegistry.java:137)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry$TypeCodecCacheLoader.load(CodecRegistry.java:246)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry$TypeCodecCacheLoader.load(CodecRegistry.java:232)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3628)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2336)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2295)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2208)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4053)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4057)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4986)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.lookupCodec(CodecRegistry.java:522)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.codecFor(CodecRegistry.java:485)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.codecFor(CodecRegistry.java:467)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableByIndexData.codecFor(AbstractGettableByIndexData.java:69)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableByIndexData.getLong(AbstractGettableByIndexData.java:152)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableData.getLong(AbstractGettableData.java:26)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableData.getLong(AbstractGettableData.java:95)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.cassandra.CassandraServiceImpl.getTokenRanges(CassandraServiceImpl.java:279)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.cassandra.CassandraServiceImpl.getEstimatedSizeBytes(CassandraServiceImpl.java:135)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.cassandra.CassandraIO$CassandraSource.getEstimatedSizeBytes(CassandraIO.java:308)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.BoundedReadEvaluatorFactory$BoundedReadEvaluator.startDynamicSplitThread(BoundedReadEvaluatorFactory.java:166)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.BoundedReadEvaluatorFactory$BoundedReadEvaluator.processElement(BoundedReadEvaluatorFactory.java:142)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.TransformExecutor.processElements(TransformExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.TransformExecutor.run(TransformExecutor.java:110)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

### Pipeline read code

```
// Read data from Cassandra table
PCollection<Model> pcollection = p.apply(CassandraIO.<Model>read()
        .withHosts(Arrays.asList("10.10.10.101", "10.10.10.102", "10.10.10.103", "10.10.10.104")).withPort(9042)
        .withKeyspace(keyspaceName).withTable(tableName)
        .withEntity(Model.class).withCoder(SerializableCoder.of(Model.class))
        .withConsistencyLevel(CASSA_CONSISTENCY_LEVEL));

// Transform pcollection to KV PCollection by rowName
PCollection<KV<Long, Model>> pcollection_by_rowName = pcollection
        .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<Model, KV<Long, Model>>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                c.output(KV.of(c.element().rowName, c.element()));
            }
        }));
```

### Number of splits (Stackdriver log)

```
W  Number of splits is less than 0 (0), fallback to 1 
I  Number of splits is 1 
W  Number of splits is less than 0 (0), fallback to 1 
I  Number of splits is 1 
W  Number of splits is less than 0 (0), fallback to 1 
I  Number of splits is 1
```

## What I'v tried

No effect:

1. set read consistency level to ONE
2. `nodetool setstreamthroughput 1000`, `nodetool setinterdcstreamthroughput 1000`
3. increase Cassandra read concurrency (in `cassandra.yaml`): `concurrent_reads: 32`
4. setting different number of workers 1-40.

Some effect:
 1. I'v set numSplits = 10 as @jkff proposed. Now I can see in logs:

```
I  Murmur3Partitioner detected, splitting 
W  Can't estimate the size 
W  Can't estimate the size 
W  Number of splits is less than 0 (0), fallback to 10 
I  Number of splits is 10 
W  Number of splits is less than 0 (0), fallback to 10 
I  Number of splits is 10 
I  Splitting source org.apache.beam.sdk.io.cassandra.CassandraIO$CassandraSource@6d83ee93 produced 10 bundles with total serialized response size 20799 
I  Splitting source org.apache.beam.sdk.io.cassandra.CassandraIO$CassandraSource@25d02f5c produced 10 bundles with total serialized response size 19359 
I  Splitting source [0, 1) produced 1 bundles with total serialized response size 1091 
I  Murmur3Partitioner detected, splitting 
W  Can't estimate the size 
I  Splitting source [0, 0) produced 0 bundles with total serialized response size 76 
W  Number of splits is less than 0 (0), fallback to 10 
I  Number of splits is 10 
I  Splitting source org.apache.beam.sdk.io.cassandra.CassandraIO$CassandraSource@2661dcf3 produced 10 bundles with total serialized response size 18527
```

But I'v got another exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to start reading from source: org.apache.beam.sdk.io.cassandra.Cassandra...
(5d6339652002918d): java.io.IOException: Failed to start reading from source: org.apache.beam.sdk.io.cassandra.CassandraIO$CassandraSource@5f18c296
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$BoundedReaderIterator.start(WorkerCustomSources.java:582)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation$SynchronizedReaderIterator.start(ReadOperation.java:347)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:183)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:148)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:68)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:336)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:294)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:244)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:135)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:115)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:53 mismatched character 'p' expecting '$'
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:58)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:24)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:68)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:43)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.cassandra.CassandraServiceImpl$CassandraReaderImpl.start(CassandraServiceImpl.java:80)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources$BoundedReaderIterator.start(WorkerCustomSources.java:579)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:53 mismatched character 'p' expecting '$'
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:144)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:179)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:186)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2500(RequestHandler.java:50)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:817)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:651)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1077)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1000)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:642)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:565)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:479)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:441)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    ... 1 more
```

Maybe there is a mistake: [CassandraServiceImpl.java#L220](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/cassandra/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/cassandra/CassandraServiceImpl.java#L220)

And this statement looks like mistype: [CassandraServiceImpl.java#L207](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.1.1/sdks/java/io/cassandra/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/cassandra/CassandraServiceImpl.java#L207)

## Changes I'v done to CassandraIO code

As @jkff proposed, I've change CassandraIO in the way I needed:

```
@VisibleForTesting
protected List<BoundedSource<T>> split(CassandraIO.Read<T> spec,
                                              long desiredBundleSizeBytes,
                                              long estimatedSizeBytes) {
  long numSplits = 1;
  List<BoundedSource<T>> sourceList = new ArrayList<>();
  if (desiredBundleSizeBytes > 0) {
    numSplits = estimatedSizeBytes / desiredBundleSizeBytes;
  }
  if (numSplits <= 0) {
    LOG.warn("Number of splits is less than 0 ({}), fallback to 10", numSplits);
    numSplits = 10;
  }

  LOG.info("Number of splits is {}", numSplits);

  Long startRange = MIN_TOKEN;
  Long endRange = MAX_TOKEN;
  Long startToken, endToken;

  String pk = "$pk";
  switch (spec.table()) {
  case "table1":
          pk = "table1_pk";
          break;
  case "table2":
  case "table3":
          pk = "table23_pk";
          break;
  }

  endToken = startRange;
  Long incrementValue = endRange / numSplits - startRange / numSplits;
  String splitQuery;
  if (numSplits == 1) {
    // we have an unique split
    splitQuery = QueryBuilder.select().from(spec.keyspace(), spec.table()).toString();
    sourceList.add(new CassandraIO.CassandraSource<T>(spec, splitQuery));
  } else {
    // we have more than one split
    for (int i = 0; i < numSplits; i++) {
      startToken = endToken;
      endToken = startToken + incrementValue;
      Select.Where builder = QueryBuilder.select().from(spec.keyspace(), spec.table()).where();
      if (i > 0) {
        builder = builder.and(QueryBuilder.gte("token(" + pk + ")", startToken));
      }
      if (i < (numSplits - 1)) {
        builder = builder.and(QueryBuilder.lt("token(" + pk + ")", endToken));
      }
      sourceList.add(new CassandraIO.CassandraSource(spec, builder.toString()));
    }
  }
  return sourceList;
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to use Dataflow? You could just export to CSV and then bulk load.

Comment: Can you show relevant parts of your pipeline code?

Comment: From the background information you have provided, I believe the cluster host connectivity error / table size estimation warning you have highlighted is causing the job's read parallelism to be limited to one worker.

Comment: I'v edited question. I need to transform data before writing it to BQ. @GrahamPolley

Comment: I'v edited the question. You can look at my reading code [here](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1691645). @jkff

Comment: You could always do your transformations post load using SQL or JavaScript.

Comment: (I've direclty incuded your snipper)

Comment: Thanks. Do you see any logging in Stackdriver for your dataflow jobs coming from CassandraIO, e.g. logging about number of splits it decided to use for reading? E.g. here https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/cassandra/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/cassandra/CassandraServiceImpl.java#L200

Comment: I'v added log output to my question.  Number of splits is 1. @jkff

Comment: I'v launched pipeline from GCE VM. Now I get another warning (question edited). @AndrewMo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be classified as a bug in CassandraIO. I filed [BEAM-3424](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3424). You can try building your own version of Beam with that default of 1 changed to 100 or something like that, while this issue is being fixed.

I also filed [BEAM-3425](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3425) for the bug during size estimation.

Comment: A reasonable default, for the number of read-splits, may be the number of hosts the user has identified as coordinator/seed nodes for the Cassandra ring in their connection settings

Comment: Can I add custom codec [varchar <-> Long] to solve the problem? How can I get Cassandra Cluster instance within my pipeline?

Comment: I think the best way to go for you right now would be to build your own patched version of the CassandraIO module, changing the number at https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/cassandra/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/cassandra/CassandraServiceImpl.java#L197 from 1 to something else. Or send a PR to Beam to make these fixes if you'd like - I'll be happy to review :) See https://beam.apache.org/contribute/contribution-guide/

Comment: I'v set numSplits = 10 as you proposed. But I'v got another exception. (I'v update the question).

Comment: Ugh :( I guess this bug was masked by the other two issues. Filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3485 . Again the only thing I can recommend for the moment is make the fix yourself and build a patched version of beam; if it works, I'd be happy to review the PR: right now I'm overwhelmed with other things and don't have time to fix this myself; I don't know what JB's (CassandraIO author) availability is like.