# How to prevent decrease of Dataflow read parallelism from Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

You can read about my setup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48090668/how-to-increase-dataflow-read-parallelism-from-cassandra). I solved problems, described there, but I have new one.

I am reading the data from 3 tables. I have problem with one (the largest) table. I've read a lot of data from the table with great rate ~300000 rows/s, but after ~10 hours (and when reading from other two tables finished) it decreased to ~20000 rows/s. And after 24 hours it's not finished yet.

There are a lot of suspicious lines in the log:

```
I  Proposing dynamic split of work unit cybrmt;2018-01-17_22_54_11-12138573770170126316;3251780906818434621 at {"fractionConsumed":0.5} 
I  Rejecting split request because custom reader returned null residual source. 
I  Proposing dynamic split of work unit cybrmt;2018-01-17_22_54_11-12138573770170126316;3251780906818434621 at {"fractionConsumed":0.5} 
I  Rejecting split request because custom reader returned null residual source. 
I  Proposing dynamic split of work unit cybrmt;2018-01-17_22_54_11-12138573770170126316;3251780906818434621 at {"fractionConsumed":0.5} 
I  Rejecting split request because custom reader returned null residual source. 
I  Proposing dynamic split of work unit cybrmt;2018-01-17_22_54_11-12138573770170126316;3251780906818434621 at {"fractionConsumed":0.5} 
I  Rejecting split request because custom reader returned null residual source. 
I  Proposing dynamic split of work unit cybrmt;2018-01-17_22_54_11-12138573770170126316;3251780906818434621 at {"fractionConsumed":0.5} 
I  Rejecting split request because custom reader returned null residual source. 
I  Proposing dynamic split of work unit cybrmt;2018-01-17_22_54_11-12138573770170126316;3251780906818434621 at {"fractionConsumed":0.5} 
I  Rejecting split request because custom reader returned null residual source. 
I  Proposing dynamic split of work unit cybrmt;2018-01-17_22_54_11-12138573770170126316;3251780906818434621 at {"fractionConsumed":0.5} 
I  Rejecting split request because custom reader returned null residual source.
```

## UPD

The job ended with exception:

```
(f000632be487340d): Workflow failed. Causes: (844d65bb40eb132b): S14:Read from Cassa table/Read(CassandraSource)+Transform to KV by id+CoGroupByKey id/MakeUnionTable0+CoGroupByKey id/GroupByKey/Reify+CoGroupByKey id/GroupByKey/Write failed., (c07ceebe5d95f668): A work item was attempted 4 times without success. Each time the worker eventually lost contact with the service. The work item was attempted on: 
  starterpipeline-sosenko19-01172254-4260-harness-wrdk,
  starterpipeline-sosenko19-01172254-4260-harness-xrkd,
  starterpipeline-sosenko19-01172254-4260-harness-hvfd,
  starterpipeline-sosenko19-01172254-4260-harness-0pf5
```

### About CoGroupByKey

There are two tables. One have ~2 billion rows, each with unique key (1 row per key). Second have ~20 billion rows with less or equal 10 rows per key.

### Graph of the pipeline

[image]

Here is what inside `CoGroupByKey match_id` block:

[image]

### Code of the pipeline

```
// Create pipeline
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create());

// Read data from Cassandra table opendota_player_match_by_account_id2
PCollection<OpendotaPlayerMatch> player_matches = p.apply("Read from Cassa table opendota_player_match_by_account_id2", CassandraIO.<OpendotaPlayerMatch>read()
        .withHosts(Arrays.asList("10.132.9.101", "10.132.9.102", "10.132.9.103", "10.132.9.104")).withPort(9042)
        .withKeyspace("cybermates").withTable(CASSA_OPENDOTA_PLAYER_MATCH_BY_ACCOUNT_ID_TABLE_NAME)
        .withEntity(OpendotaPlayerMatch.class).withCoder(SerializableCoder.of(OpendotaPlayerMatch.class))
        .withConsistencyLevel(CASSA_CONSISTENCY_LEVEL));

// Transform player_matches to KV by match_id
PCollection<KV<Long, OpendotaPlayerMatch>> opendota_player_matches_by_match_id = player_matches
        .apply("Transform player_matches to KV by match_id", ParDo.of(new DoFn<OpendotaPlayerMatch, KV<Long, OpendotaPlayerMatch>>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                // LOG.info(c.element().match_id.toString());
                c.output(KV.of(c.element().match_id, c.element()));
            }
        }));

// Read data from Cassandra table opendota_match
PCollection<OpendotaMatch> opendota_matches = p.apply("Read from Cassa table opendota_match", CassandraIO.<OpendotaMatch>read()
        .withHosts(Arrays.asList("10.132.9.101", "10.132.9.102", "10.132.9.103", "10.132.9.104")).withPort(9042)
        .withKeyspace("cybermates").withTable(CASSA_OPENDOTA_MATCH_TABLE_NAME).withEntity(OpendotaMatch.class)
        .withCoder(SerializableCoder.of(OpendotaMatch.class))
        .withConsistencyLevel(CASSA_CONSISTENCY_LEVEL));

// Read data from Cassandra table match
PCollection<OpendotaMatch> matches = p.apply("Read from Cassa table match", CassandraIO.<Match>read()
        .withHosts(Arrays.asList("10.132.9.101", "10.132.9.102", "10.132.9.103", "10.132.9.104")).withPort(9042)
        .withKeyspace("cybermates").withTable(CASSA_MATCH_TABLE_NAME).withEntity(Match.class)
        .withCoder(SerializableCoder.of(Match.class))
        .withConsistencyLevel(CASSA_CONSISTENCY_LEVEL))
        .apply("Adopt match for uniform structure", ParDo.of(new DoFn<Match, OpendotaMatch>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                // LOG.info(c.element().match_id.toString());
                OpendotaMatch m = new OpendotaMatch();

                // opendota_match and  match tables have slightly different schema. I've cut out conversion here because it's large and dummy

                c.output(m);
            }
        }));


// Union match and opendota_match
PCollectionList<OpendotaMatch> matches_collections = PCollectionList.of(opendota_matches).and(matches);
PCollection<OpendotaMatch> all_matches = matches_collections.apply("Union match and opendota_match", Flatten.<OpendotaMatch>pCollections());

// Transform matches to KV by match_id
PCollection<KV<Long, OpendotaMatch>> matches_by_match_id = all_matches
        .apply("Transform matches to KV by match_id", ParDo.of(new DoFn<OpendotaMatch, KV<Long, OpendotaMatch>>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                // LOG.info(c.element().players.toString());
                c.output(KV.of(c.element().match_id, c.element()));
            }
        }));

// CoGroupByKey match_id
// Replicate data
final TupleTag<OpendotaPlayerMatch> player_match_tag = new TupleTag<OpendotaPlayerMatch>();
final TupleTag<OpendotaMatch> match_tag = new TupleTag<OpendotaMatch>();
PCollection<KV<Long, PMandM>> joined_matches = KeyedPCollectionTuple
        .of(player_match_tag, opendota_player_matches_by_match_id).and(match_tag, matches_by_match_id)
        .apply("CoGroupByKey match_id", CoGroupByKey.<Long>create())
        .apply("Replicate data", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<Long, CoGbkResult>, KV<Long, PMandM>>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                try {
                    OpendotaMatch m = c.element().getValue().getAll(match_tag).iterator().next();
                    Iterable<OpendotaPlayerMatch> pms = c.element().getValue().getAll(player_match_tag);
                    for (OpendotaPlayerMatch pm : pms) {
                        if (0 <= pm.account_id && pm.account_id < MAX_UINT) {
                            for (OpendotaPlayerMatch pm2 : pms) {                                   
                                c.output(KV.of(pm.account_id, new PMandM(pm2, m)));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                    LOG.error(c.element().getValue().getAll(player_match_tag).iterator().next().match_id.toString() + " " + e.toString());
                }
            }
        }));        


// Transform to byte array
// Write to BQ
joined_matches
        .apply("Transform to byte array, Write to BQ", BigQueryIO.<KV<Long, PMandM>>write().to(new DynamicDestinations<KV<Long, PMandM>, String>() {
            public String getDestination(ValueInSingleWindow<KV<Long, PMandM>> element) {
                return element.getValue().getKey().toString();
            }

            public TableDestination getTable(String account_id_str) {
                return new TableDestination("cybrmt:" + BQ_DATASET_NAME + ".player_match_" + account_id_str,
                        "Table for user " + account_id_str);
            }

            public TableSchema getSchema(String account_id_str) {
                List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<>();
                fields.add(new TableFieldSchema().setName("value").setType("BYTES"));
                return new TableSchema().setFields(fields);
            }
        }).withFormatFunction(new SerializableFunction<KV<Long, PMandM>, TableRow>() {
            public TableRow apply(KV<Long, PMandM> element) {
                OpendotaPlayerMatch pm = element.getValue().pm;                     
                OpendotaMatch m = element.getValue().m;
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(114);

                // I've cut out transform to byte buffer here because it's large and dummy

                tr.set("value", bb.array());
                return tr;                      
            }
        }));

p.run();
```

## UPD2. I've tried to read the problem table alone

I've tried to read the problem table from above alone. Pipeline contains CassandraIO.Read transform and dummy ParDo transform with some logging output. And now it behaves like the full pipeline. There is one (I believe last) split that cannot be done:

```
I  Proposing dynamic split of work unit cybrmt;2018-01-20_21_28_01-3451798636786921663;1617811313034836533 at {"fractionConsumed":0.5} 
I  Rejecting split request because custom reader returned null residual source.
```

Here is the graph of the pipeline:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
// Create pipeline
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create());

// Read data from Cassandra table opendota_player_match_by_account_id2
PCollection<OpendotaPlayerMatch> player_matches = p.apply("Read from Cassa table opendota_player_match_by_account_id2", CassandraIO.<OpendotaPlayerMatch>read()
        .withHosts(Arrays.asList("10.132.9.101", "10.132.9.102", "10.132.9.103", "10.132.9.104")).withPort(9042)
        .withKeyspace("cybermates").withTable(CASSA_OPENDOTA_PLAYER_MATCH_BY_ACCOUNT_ID_TABLE_NAME)
        .withEntity(OpendotaPlayerMatch.class).withCoder(SerializableCoder.of(OpendotaPlayerMatch.class))
        .withConsistencyLevel(CASSA_CONSISTENCY_LEVEL));

// Print my matches
player_matches.apply("Print my matches", ParDo.of(new DoFn<OpendotaPlayerMatch, Long>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                if (c.element().account_id == 114688838) {
                    LOG.info(c.element().match_id.toString());
                    c.output(c.element().match_id);
                }
            }
        }));

p.run();
```

## UPD3

The small pipeline (CassandraIO.Read and ParDo) successfully finished in 23 hours. First 4 hours there were max number of workers (40) and great read speed (~300000 rows/s). After that number of workers autoscaled to 1 as well as read speed to ~15000 rows/s. Here is the graph:

[image]

And here is the log end:

```
I  Proposing dynamic split of work unit cybrmt;2018-01-20_21_28_01-3451798636786921663;1617811313034836533 at {"fractionConsumed":0.5} 
I  Rejecting split request because custom reader returned null residual source. 
I  Proposing dynamic split of work unit cybrmt;2018-01-20_21_28_01-3451798636786921663;1617811313034836533 at {"fractionConsumed":0.5} 
I  Rejecting split request because custom reader returned null residual source. 
I  Success processing work item cybrmt;2018-01-20_21_28_01-3451798636786921663;1617811313034836533 
I  Finished processing stage s01 with 0 errors in 75268.681 seconds
```

Comment: Can you share a job id?

Comment: Sure, @jkff. Job ID: 2018-01-17_22_54_11-12138573770170126316

Comment: In the last exception I got (see question) it is said: "GroupByKey/Write failed". @jkff

Comment: "lost contact with the service" typically means the worker crashed for some reason, e.g. OOM. Are you seeing anything like that in Stackdriver logs? Is your job e.g. performing a join with a really large amount of data per key, or something like that? It would help if you shared some code - but this error is no longer related to reading from Cassandra, I believe.

Comment: I had OOM errors before (and it was in log), but I've changed machine type to `n1-highmem-2` and errors are gone. The error message in question is the only one error message I see in log. My job is performing `CoGroupByKey` operation (see pipeline graph and code) with ~10 rows per key (~2 billion keys). @jkff

Comment: I've tried CassandraIO.Read transform alone. I've got the same problem (see question for details). @jkff

Comment: My experiment with small pipeline successfully finished, but there is problem with read speed (see question).

Comment: OK, the read speed issue looks a straggler - to combat that, you can either try specifying significantly more splits, or CassandraIO will need to implement dynamic rebalancing https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/05/no-shard-left-behind-dynamic-work-rebalancing-in-google-cloud-dataflow (the messages you're seeing are Dataflow asking it to perform it, and CassandraIO rejecting it because it's not supported). Does your table have a very unbalanced keyspace by chance?

Comment: Another performance suggestion: you have a quadratic nested loop in "Replicate data" step - any way you can refactor that? Also it might perform better if you extract "pms" into a List rather than keeping it a simple Iterable, because that Iterable is loaded lazily with caching and a nested loop may interfere with the caching.

Comment: Yes, I have one key, that holds a lot of data compared to others.Can I split read not only by partition key, but by some columns of clustering key too?
I need to write each data row into several tables (<= 10) so I replicate it in the way. Can I write to multiple tables with CassandraIO directly?
@jkff

Comment: In Cassandra, data with the same partition key is stored on the same node, so you'll be limited by the read throughput of a single Cassandra node which seems to match the performance you observed. If you're limited by the speed of *processing* the data rather than reading it, try adding a Reshuffle.viaRandomKey() between reading from Cassandra and downstream processing - it will make Dataflow materialize a copy of the data, but the copy can be processed fully in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally used @jkff advise and read the data from a table with different partition key that is distributed more evenly (there were actually two tables with the same data but different partition keys in my data schema).